# how to iterate through every x numbers and echo results in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, iteration

the question title might be a bit confuse. but here is my case.

i would like my result to like something like:

```
0000000000
    0000000001
    0000000002
    0000000003
    0000000004
    0000000005
    0000000006
    0000000007
    0000000008
    0000000009
    0000000010
0000000001
    0000000011
    0000000012
    0000000013
    0000000014
    0000000015
    0000000016
    0000000017
    0000000018
    0000000019
0000000002
    0000000020
    0000000021
    0000000022
    0000000023
    ...
0000000003
    ...
0000000004
    ...
```

i can get the first numbers by doing this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $nr=str_pad($i, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $nr.'<br>';
}
```

but then how do i get the numbers in between?

any ideas?

Thanks

edit: the second row of numbers are based on 10 by 10 count.

so. first record will have 10 other records underneath, the second record another 10 and so on.

i've tried something using `$floor= floor($i/10);` and adding that to the second set of records in here: `$nr=str_pad($floor, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Do you really want to get `0000000001` twice?

Comment: What are the second set of values iterating to?

Comment: the second set of values (the numbers in between) are from 10 to 10.

Comment: Why is `0000000010` in the first section but `0000000020` in the third?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. But one possible solution would be this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){

    if ($i % 10 == 1)
        echo str_pad(($i-1)/10, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\n";

    echo '    '.str_pad($i, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\n";
}
```

See it [in action](http://ideone.com/555rq).

Depending on your problem, using two cycles might be better for you:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

    echo str_pad($i, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\n";

    for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
        echo '    '.str_pad($i*10+$j, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/59ZoA).

Comment: nice, what if i want each sub-record to have not 10 but 100 records. Like `0000000000 -> 0000000001 ... 0000000100` then `0000000001 -> 0000000101 ... 0000000200` and so on

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could figure that out, just read through the code. Especially the double-cycle solution is very straightforward.

Comment: +1 for implementation. @Patrioticcow: my answer might help you understand how or where to make the adjustment in listing #1.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, but I would change your loop as described to iterate the secondary numbers, and then use a test such as MOD ( http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php ) to check for those times when you want to emit the first level grouping.

So you adjust your str_pad line to indent as well as left pad with 0, and add a lne near the top of the loop to check if ($i % 10 == 0) (that is, if it is divisible by 10 without a remainder).

Note this may not be the fastest nor most elegant way.